# Shell Script:How to get all the Process Id which are using a file-system/directory

Tags: bash, shell

I am checking the processes which is using a file system. Now when I do fuser there are hundreds of processes are coming.

```
fuser -cu /xyz
```

Output truncated:

```
393ce(xyz)  1044c(root)  1068cm(oracle)  2065ce(xyz)  3729ce(xyz)
```

I want just process id in file separated by newline character so that I can run a loop to check the processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want `id` instead of `id(user)` then don't use the `-u` option. Documentation of `fuser -u`:

> -u, --user
>    Append the user name of the process owner to each PID.

For me, `fuser -c /` has a different format than your sample. Each id is followed by letters denoting the type of access. The letters are printed to `stderr`, therefore I will use `2>&-` to hide them.

```
$ fuser -c /
/:                    1717rce  1754rce  1765rce  1785rce  ...
$ fuser -c / 2>&-
  1717  1754  1765  1785  ...
```

You can use `grep` to print one id per line:

```
$ fuser -c / 2>&- | grep -o '[0-9]*'
1717
1754
1765
1785
...
```

However, to run a loop you don't need one id per line. Ids separated by spaces work as well:

```
for id in $(fuser -c / 2>&-); do
    echo "id = $id"
done
```

Comment: Of course you don't really need a loop in the last case either.  `printf 'id = %s\n' $(fuser -c / 2>&-)`

Comment: @tripleee I know. The loop is only there to prove that `for` loops work with word splitting and not by reading lines. OP said *»so that I can run a loop«*. `echo` is just a placeholder. I assumed OP would do something different than just printing inside the loop.

Comment: @Socowi nice one